# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string while trying to dynamic uri source on WebView React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to make a dynamic uri source for webview react native when pressing a bottom navigation menu buttons .

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'
import { View, BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationTab, Icon } from 'react-native';

const HomeIcon = (props) => <Icon {...props} name="home" />;
const ContactUsIcon = (props) => <Icon {...props} name="contacts" />;

const WebViewExample = () => {
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('https://www.example.com');

  const handleTabPress = (index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      setCurrentUrl('https://www.example.com/home');
    } else if (index === 1) {
      setCurrentUrl('https://www.example.com/contact-us');
    }
  };

  const app = () => {
    return (
      <WebView source={{ uri: currentUrl }} />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {renderWebView()}
      <BottomNavigation selectedIndex={0} onSelect={handleTabPress}>
        <BottomNavigationTab title="Home" icon={HomeIcon} />
        <BottomNavigationTab title="Contact Us" icon={ContactUsIcon} />
      </BottomNavigation>
    </View>
  );
};

export default app;
```

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `app`

keep getting this error and i don't understand exactly what the problem , any ideas ?

I am trying to make a dynamic uri source for webview react native when pressing a bottom navigation menu buttons .

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple issue with your code.

1. A component name must start with an upper case letter. it must be `App` not `app`.
2. you have forgot some brackets.
3. renderWebView is not a function.
4. There is no navigation in react-native, you have to use third party package like [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) to handle navigation.
5. for Icon you have to user [react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)